# SSIS or Sync Framework with Change Tracking

Tags: sql-server-2008, ssis, microsoft-sync-framework, change-tracking

Until now, I have worked primarily with LAMP applications, but have a project in which I need to set up two-way syncing between two SQL 2008 servers (one is web-based, the other is inside a firewall).  I am finding a plethora of detailed information, but am having trouble answering some basic questions (in bold below).

As I understand it based on my reading to this point:

- Replication is an end-to-end solution that can solve many common problems but is not as flexible as other options.
- Change Tracking (SQL >= 2008) can record information about DB transactions and store the information in system tables.  This information can be accessed via standard SQL queries and used in conjunction with with other tools to build a complete syncing solution.
- Sync Framework is a framework that can be used in conjunction with programming languages (and change tracking) for a complete and flexible syncing solution.
- SQL Server Integration Services (SSIS) is typically used when integrating SQL Server data with another data source.  The development environment is easy to learn and fast to develop in.  I believe this is also an end-to-end solution, but it can also be used in conjunction with other programming languages (creating new tasks, etc.).

Based on those understandings, here are my solutions:

I have some fairly complex logic for resolving syncing conflicts, which rules out replication (merge replication may be able to handle the logic, but it sound like the overhead would be much greater than with other solutions available in SQL 2008).

Being new to SQL Server, I really like what I have read about the ease of using SSIS, however most articles/examples I have read indicate it is primarily for integrating SQL Server with other data sources.  **Is SSIS an appropriate solution for syncing?**  I would also like to use the data recorded by 2008's Change Tracking, **can I access this data through SSIS?**

The other option would be using the Sync Framework and Change Tracking, which would involve a much steeper learning curve.  **What are the benefits of using this combination rather than SSIS and Change Tracking?**

All comments on my understanding of MS syncing technologies and my solutions are appreciated.

Chris

Comment: In your nomenclature, is syncing different than integrating? The desired end result is the data matches between system A and B, yes? SSIS can do that. SSIS allows for using most anything as a source of data. CDC data, as you've already noted, can be accessed through standard SQL queries. Paste said query into an appropriate source transformation and voila, it flows down the pipe.  I have not touched the sync framework which is why this is a comment and not an answer

Comment: @billinkc Thank you for your response, that gets me half way there!  You are exactly right that the desired end result is that the data matches between systems.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Found a nice summary that explains when to use each technology [here](http://www.bidn.com/blogs/MarkGStacey/bidn-blog/853/microsoft-integration-stack)

Comment: one of the key things you have to take into consideration here is the firewalls. are you willing to open up ports to allow direct SQL server access?

Comment: Good point. Our security folks looked at VPN, but settled on Layer 2 tunnelling.